# css display: box with box-align stretch and center at the same time

Tags: css

So I have a flex-box, or more precisely only a box (`display: box`) since that's what Sass Compass generates.

I want it to:

1. base it's height on its content
2. make the "columns" stretch so that their backgrounds fill the entire parent
3. have the content of the columns vertically centered.

Like so:

[image: bad flex-box]

[see it on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oxovaq/1/edit)

The problem is that requirement 2 and requirement 3 in the list above collide. I can have the content vertically centered with `box-align: center` but to have the backgrounds stretch I must use `box-align: stretch`.

In the example above I'm using

```css
#div1 { display: table; height: 150px; }
#div1 > div { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
```

The problem is that I can't specify a fixed height since the height is decided by the content of the 3rd column (lime).

Any way to solve this without javascript? Nested flex-boxes (tried but can't get to work)? display: table as above?

Comment: If you already use flexboxes, you can make your 2nd column a flexbox, too (with vertical orientation) and center its content: http://jsbin.com/oxovaq/28/edit. But I have to notice that you use [the outdated flexbox syntax](http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/‎), `display: -ms-box` and `display: box` will never be supported. Also, `-webkit-box` and `moz-box` seem to behave differently, the current syntax `display: flex` behaves more like Webkit.

Comment: That worked fantastically well! I'm using the outdated one since that's what SASS Compass generates. Is my Compass version (0.12.2) outdated maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need for the flex box css if you are just trying to get three columns of equal height, that grow with the content and have vertical alignment

If you just use the following structure

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell" id="cell1"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="cell2"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="cell3"></div>
</div>
```

You can use these styles:

```css
.table {display:table; width:100%;}
.cell {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; width:33.33%;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bw4Pq/)

Comment: That's a good question. I'm doing a mobile app and I saw that mobile browsers had quite good support for flex-box, so I figured I'd try it out. But sure, maybe it's simpler using `display:table`. For people reading this quickly: note that Ilya Streltsyn has a comment above which makes the flex-box way work!